# How to make use of indexes with inner join in Postgis?

Tags: index, join, postgis

I got 2 sets of points in 2 separate tables. Table_a got 100k points and table_b got 300k of points. I trying to find nearest points in relation find me any point from table_b that is within 50 meters from tabla_a. After that calculate fall column, group them by table_a a_id column and return highest value.

I wrote a following query that meet this criteira

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a_id) *
FROM (
       SELECT
         table_b.b_id,
         table_b.height - st_3ddistance(table_b.geom, table_a.geom) fall,
         table_b.geom,
         table_a.a_id
       FROM table_a
         INNER JOIN table_b ON _st_3ddwithin(table_a.geom, table_b.geom, 50)) a
WHERE fall >= 0
ORDER BY a_id, fall DESC;
```

I added 3d geometry indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX table_a_geom ON table_a USING GIST (geom gist_geometry_ops_nd);
CREATE INDEX table_b_geom ON table_b USING GIST (geom gist_geometry_ops_nd);
```

However my problem is that i can't make query to use them. Query planer is keep choosing sequence scan that is slow. I run some test changing ***_st_3ddwithin*** with ***st_3ddwithin***, ***<<->> < 50*** , creating ***50 m buffer and intersect***, ***st_3ddistance < 50*** but everytime planner is choosing sequence scan. Is there a way to use indexes with higher performance?

My query plan:

```
Unique  (cost=10462593.70..10473018.43 rows=1 width=144)
  ->  Sort  (cost=10462593.70..10467806.06 rows=2084945 width=144)
        Sort Key: table_a.nmbayuid, ((table_b.height - st_3ddistance(table_b.geomgr, table_a.geom))) DESC
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..10243762.28 rows=2084945 width=144)
              Join Filter: (_st_dwithin(table_a.geom, table_b.geomgr, '50'::double precision) AND ((table_b.height - st_3ddistance(table_b.geomgr, table_a.geom)) >= '0'::double precision))
              ->  Seq Scan on e_veg_points_mv12404 table_b  (cost=0.00..1459.47 rows=47147 width=96)
              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..10.97 rows=398 width=56)
                    ->  Seq Scan on e_wires_mv12404 table_a  (cost=0.00..8.98 rows=398 width=56)
```